# Advanced search?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way or proposal for an advanced search feature? Examples being search for questions/answers with multiple tags, with bounties, that are X amount of months old with X rating, etc.
From the similar questions already asked, none of them really answer my question.

Comment: [These](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=) are the features currently in place. For the ones you've mentioned, the only one you can do is multiple tags; all others are not possible. If you want a specific feature and can't find a [meta-tag:feature-request] for it here on meta, then I suggest your post be limited to that specific feature.

Comment: I too would like a list of all the X-rated posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do all of them, except search for something that's X months old. For the rest:

1. Questions/Answers: `is:question` or `is:answer`
2. Multiple tags: `[tag1] [tag2]`
3. Bounty: Go to `site.com/?tab=featured` or if you want it in a particular tag, go to the featured tab in that tag. e.g., `site.com/questions/tagged/tag1?sort=featured`
4. X rating (I assume you mean votes): `votes:X` will return posts which have at least X votes.

Answer (score 2):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is a read-only copy of (most of) the Stack Exchange database. It is updated approximately once a month, so it's only good for searching amongst old posts. You can make searches as complex as you can express in SQL.

If you want up-to-date data, you can retrieve a set of questions with the [Stack Exchange API](https://stackapps.com/about) and perform further processing on your machine. This is only practical if you can use some simple filtering (on [tags, title words](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/search) or [question](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions) or [answer](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/answers) dates or ids) to get down a superset of at most a few hundred posts.